# Is there a way to copy text from two cells into another spreadsheet only if another cell has a YES?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to copy the text in Cells A1 and B1 into another spreadsheet that will be emailed out, but only if the text in Cell E1 has a "YES" in it.

How would I go about doing something like this in Google Sheets?

Comment: Hey @Amel, you can try the functions switch + importrange.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to copy text from two cells into another spreadsheet
>   only if another cell has a YES?

Yes, assuming A1 and A2 are in Sheet1 and your YES is in Sheet2 the following code will import the information into Sheet2:

```
=if(E1="YES",Sheet1!A1&Sheet2!A2,"")
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully! Thank you!